# casting object to sql TIMESTAMP throwing java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858

Tags: java, timestamp, prepared-statement

I have a list of Objects which are set to prepared statement. I have a timestamp value in the list and hence checking the `instanceOf` condition and `preparedStatement.setTimestamp` to set the value, but it is throwing  `java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01858 a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`. Is the explicit casting a problem ?

My code

```
int count = 1;
for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
    logger.info("column: "+count+ " value: "+list.get(j));
    if(list.get(j) instanceof Timestamp) {
          ps.setTimestamp(count,  (Timestamp) list.get(j));     
    } else {
         ps.setObject(count, list.get(j));
    }
    count++;
```

}

Prepared Statement

```
insert  into OPRS_ZONES(ZONE_ID,ZONE_CODE,ZONE_NAME,PLACE_ID,CORP_ID,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,MODIFIED_BY,MODIFIED_DATE) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Values

```
column: 1 value: 03.0
column: 2 value: 'HYDERABAD'
column: 3 value: 'HYDERABAD'
column: 4 value: 05231.0
column: 5 value: 01.0
column: 6 value: 01.0
column: 7 value: 2012-10-19 13:06:39.0
column: 8 value: 00.0
column: 9 value: NULL
```

Tabel structure to which i need to insert the values

```
CREATE TABLE OPRS_ZONES (
    ZONE_ID             NUMERIC(20,0)
    , ZONE_CODE         VARCHAR2(16)
    , ZONE_NAME         VARCHAR2(255)
    , PLACE_ID          NUMERIC(20,0)
    , CORP_ID           NUMERIC(20,0)
    , CREATED_BY        NUMERIC(20,0)
    , CREATED_DATE      DATE
    , MODIFIED_BY       NUMERIC(20,0)
    , MODIFIED_DATE     DATE
  );
```

Any inputs are appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in the TimeStamp column/parameter?

Comment: i have included my prepared statement and the corresponding values. Please let me know where i am going wrong? Why do i get the ORA-01858 a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected, if the date column is right ?

Comment: Can you also show how the table was created, i.e., what are the types of each column?

Comment: Have you tried running this query in your PL/SQL tool? Did it work there? By the way, I don't know how your table was designed, but _maybe_ `ZONE_CODE` is a numeric value and you're sending `'HYDERABAD'`.

Comment: i am using sql developer and it inserts value to the table without any problem. I have added the table creation script

Comment: Are you sure that `Date` and `Timestamp` are compatible datatypes between Oracle and Java?

Comment: Please show the type of each of your arguments (i.e. `list.get(j).getClass()` for each value).

Comment: value: class java.lang.String
value: class java.lang.String
value: class java.lang.String
value: class java.lang.String
value: class java.lang.String
value: class java.sql.Timestamp
value: class java.lang.String
value: class java.lang.String

Comment: @Jon Skeet, this is the problem. I am getting values as Strings. I need to convert them to numeric where it is expected to be numeric. But the problem is i am creating the prepared statement dynamically.

Comment: @user1103504: So do you have any evidence that it's actually the timestamp column which is causing the problem? It sounds like that's the only one which *is* of the right type. Is the value of the last argument literally "NULL"? (That could easily be the problem.) I would *really* try to avoid using string values like this. You should know the type of value you're trying to set, and convert appropriately.